# NodeJS Mongodb distinct to array does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

Hello try to use an mongodb distinct query with NodeJS (Async). In the GUI of Mongo this query works but in Node it returns the following error

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).distinct(...).toArray is not a function
```

The error returns on the following statement:

```
mongo.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
    console.info('MONGODB START CHECK COLLECTIONS')
    var tasks = [   // Load businessrules
        function (callback) {
            db.collection('businessrules').find({typeBusinessRule: 'SpiderGraphExeption'}).toArray(function (err, businessrules) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.businessrules = businessrules;
                callback();
            });
        },
        // Load stgOmniTracker
        function (callback) {
            db.collection('stgOmniTracker').find({}).toArray(function (err, tickets) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.tickets = tickets;
                callback();
            });
        },
        // HERE STARTS THE ERROR
        function (callback) {
            db.collection('stgOmniTracker').distinct("Responsible Group").toArray(function (err, group) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.group = group;
                callback();
            });
        }
    ];
    console.info('--------------- START ASYNC ------------------------')
    async.parallel(tasks, function (err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        var businessrules = locals.businessrules, tickets = locals.tickets, resultSet = {}, aggCountsPerDayCattegory = [], group = locals.group
        db.close()
}
```

I hope you can help me to fix this. Manny Thanks

Erik

Comment: `distinct` takes a second argument right,a query? are you using it?

Comment: Yes, but this is already in the statement, see the the example of the url https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: did you gave an empty object as the second argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [mongodb docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct) you can see that `distinct` returns `null`.

> **distinct(key[, query][, options], callback)**
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
> key (string) – key to run distinct against.
> [query] (object) – option query to narrow the returned objects.
> [options] (object) – additional options during update.
> callback (function) – this will be called after executing this method. 
>   The first parameter will contain the Error object if an error occured, or null otherwise. 
>   While the second parameter will contain the results from distinct or null if an error occured.
> ```
>
> **Returns:    **
>
> `null`

It takes a callback as the last argument. In this callback, the second argument contains the results you are looking for.

So your updated code would look like this:

```
function (callback) {
  db.collection('stgOmniTracker')
    .distinct("Responsible Group", function (err, group) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        locals.group = group;
        callback();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection('stgOmniTracker').distinct("Responsible Group", function(err, result)
{
//your code here
});
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.